# Casework Counting - Amusement Park Tokens

Tags: combinatorics

At an amusement park, there are three rides that take three tokens each, and one ride that takes four tokens.  If you have 14 tokens, and you want to ride at least one of the rides, in how many ways can you spend your tokens?  Assume the order of the rides does not matter, and you may have some remaining tokens at the end of the day.

I used casework.

Let A<sub>3</sub>, B<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>3</sub> be the three rides that take 3 tokens each and D<sub>4</sub> be the ride that takes 4 tokens.

Case 1.  One ride only.  Then I have four ways to spend my tokens:

A<sub>3</sub>

B<sub>3</sub>

C<sub>3</sub>

D<sub>4</sub>

Case 2.  Two rides.  There are six ways to spend my tokens:

A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>

A<sub>3</sub>C<sub>3</sub>

A<sub>3</sub>D<sub>4</sub>

B<sub>3</sub>C<sub>3</sub>

B<sub>3</sub>D<sub>4</sub>

C<sub>3</sub>D<sub>4</sub>

Case 3.  Three rides.  There are three ways to spend my tokens:

A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>C<sub>3</sub>

A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>D<sub>4</sub>

B<sub>3</sub>C<sub>3</sub>D<sub>4</sub>

Case 4.  Four rides.  There is one way to spend my tokens:

A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>C<sub>3</sub>D<sub>4</sub>

These 14 ways satisfy the requirements:  total tokens not exceeding 14, order of rides does not matter, I get to ride at least one of the rides and I may have some remaining tokens.

But the answer is NOT 14.  The answer is 15.  What am I missing?  The case where I do not ride anything doesn't satisfy the "at least one ride" requirement, so that can't be the reason.

Thanks for your help -

Comment: And is it mentioned that you can't ride the same ride twice?

Comment: @SohamSaha Right about the D4 subscript.  My mistake.  Fixed in question.

Comment: The question didn't mention anything about not allowing riding the same ride more than once, and I thought about the same, but the total would balloon way over 15 really quickly (e.g. AAB, AAC, AAD...).

Comment: You've missed A3C3D4

Comment: In these types of situations, you can check if you've covered all possible cases just by using the number of permutations or combination. For case 3, its $\binom{4}{3}=4$ cases, so...

Answer (score 0):

**Store and inventory**

write $(1+ t^3A)$ meaning that ride A is not done or is done exactly one time.

Consider the product $(1+ t^3A)(1+ t^3B)(1+ t^3C)(1+ t^4D) $ that will cover all the possibilities to spend the tokens.

Their product is

$$ 1 + t^3(A + B + C) + t^4D + t^6 (AB + AC + BC)+ t^7(AD + BD + CD)+ t^9ABC + t^{10} (ABD + ACD + BCD) + t^{13}ABCD  $$

If one ride is to be done more than one time, consider multiplying expressions like

$(1+ t^3A + t^6AA + t^9AAA + t^{12}AAAA)$